# Why are fundamental weights denoted by omega?

Tags: lie-algebras, ho.history-overview, notation, coxeter-groups, root-systems

In my field (and many others, I believe) the absolutely standard notation for the fundamental weights of a root system is lowercase omega: $\omega$. Recently I was taken aback to receive a copyedited version of my paper from a journal with this notation replaced throughout with a glyph variant of the lowercase letter pi: $\varpi$. When I expressed my confusion, the editor responded that they believe the notation $\omega$ to be the result of people misinterpreting $\varpi$ as a variant of $\omega$. They added that canonical texts such as Bourbaki books used $\varpi$.

Leaving aside the appropriateness of such copyediting, the claim itself is curious. Can anyone confirm or disprove that the notation $\omega$ originated as a corruption of $\varpi$? Does anyone know which texts were the first to use $\omega$? (I have noticed that the 1987 English translation of Serre's "Complex Semisimple Lie Algebras" uses $\omega$. I do not know what notation is used in the 1966 original, is it really $\varpi$?)

Comment: Do you think it's pi for "poid"? Greek letters that look like w for weight also fit...

Comment: Random claim from Wikipedia: "Fundamental weights of a representation (probably to better distinguish from elements {\displaystyle w}w of the Weyl group, than the usual notation {\displaystyle \omega }\omega )." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_(letter)#Variant_pi

Comment: @Sam, pi for "poid" seems very plausible, yes. The Wikipedia claim is certainly not wrong, $\varpi$ and even $\pi$ are indeed found in the literature: see, respectively, "Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category O" by Humphreys and "Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups" by Vinberg-Onischik for some well-known examples. The question is whether $\omega$ really originated as a corruption of $\varpi$.

Comment: Btw, by searching "poids fondamentaux" I found that this version of Serre's original uses $\omega$: https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=hLg-AAAAIAAJ Of course, this is hardly a scan of the 1966 edition, so this may not be his original notation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had also always assumed that $\omega$ was a corruption of $\varpi$, but I have no historical evidence to back it up.  (That such corruptions can occur, even among professional mathematicians, is not to be doubted; I remember a paper that genuinely made no distinction between the letter $o$ and the number $0$, for example using them interchangeably as subscripts and meaning the same object thereby.) \\ @JimHumphreys, whose opinion on this should be valued much more than mine, is active here, and perhaps can tell us why he chose $\varpi$.

Comment: Talking about corruption of notation, in the English translations of Bourbaki's Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, fundamental weights are denoted by $\overline{\omega}$ on p. 180 of Chapter VI (Second Volume of the English translation) and by $\varpi$ at the last two lines on p. 347 and the first few lines on p. 348 of Chapter IX (Third volume of the English translation). The first occurence must be the contribution of the typist . . .

Comment: It can be traced at least to E. Cartan 1913 paper "Les groupes projectifs qui ne laissent invariante aucune multiplicité plane" (http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1913__41__53_1.pdf), where he uses $\omega$ for roots and $\varpi$ for weights.

Comment: It is my understanding that some people liked the $\varpi$ exactly because only the incrowd understood it stands for poid.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky:  It goes back further than that.  In Cartan's paper *Sur la réduction à sa form canonique de la structure d'un groupe de transformations fini et continu*, Amer. J. of Math. **18** (1896), 1–61, he uses $\varpi$ for the roots on page 19.  In his thesis of 1894, he used $\omega$.

Comment: @LSpice, I only just noticed the last sentence in your comment. I was secretly hoping for an input from him as well but now I noticed that someone added a "-2020" to his Wiki page. I found no confirmation of this whatsoever and I hope that this is some kind of unfortunate mistake.

Comment: The date was added August 28, so I think we would have heard if it were so:  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=James_E._Humphreys&type=revision&diff=975469543&oldid=950407297 .

Comment: Sadly, Paul Gunnells confirms that Jim has pased away.